# Laravel Eloquent: Join two tables

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

I have a problem with an eloquent statement.

I have two tables

Table 1 (ORDER_DETAILS)

| FORM_ID | ORDER_ID | DETAIL_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | X1 | B1 | Test |
| A1 | X1 | B3 | 10;20 |
| A2 | X2 | B10 | Test 2 |
| A2 | X2 | B20 | 1;2 |
| A2 | X2 | B30 | A;B;C |
| A3 | X3 | B200 | X;Y;Z |
| A3 | X3 | B300 | Test 3 |
| A4 | X4 | B1000 | L;M;O |

Table 2 (FORM_DETAIL)

| FORM_ID | DETAIL_ID | MOD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | Text |
| A1 | B2 | Input |
| A1 | B3 | Select |
| A2 | B10 | Input |
| A2 | B20 | Select |
| A2 | B30 | Select |
| A3 | B100 | Text |
| A3 | B200 | Select |
| A3 | B300 | Input |
| A4 | B1000 | Select |
| A4 | B2000 | Text |
| A4 | B3000 | Text |
| A4 | B4000 | Input |
| A4 | B5000 | Input |

Now I would like to bring them together for example when I call the ORDER_ID X1.

| FORM_ID | ORDER_ID | DETAIL_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | X1 | B1 | Test |
| A1 | X1 | B2 | null |
| A1 | X1 | B3 | 10;20 |

or the ORDER_ID X4

| FORM_ID | ORDER_ID | DETAIL_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A4 | X4 | B1000 | L;M;O |
| A4 | X4 | B2000 | null |
| A4 | X4 | B3000 | null |
| A4 | X4 | B4000 | null |
| A4 | X4 | B5000 | null |

All values from the table 2 (FORM_DETAIL) should always be displayed and
check whether a VALUE is intended in the table ORDER_ID X4. It is important
that FORM_ID and ORDER_ID are always identical in the
are always identical.

Can you maybe help me?

Sorry, I am still Laravel beginner :o)

Comment: Sooo, what eloquent models do you have and what relations do you have?

Comment: The tables do not have relationships. Reason: This is an old program which I have brought from Laravel 5 now to Laravel 9 and I do not know what a relationship has for effects on the rest of the code.